# Salesforce: How to get the Enterprise WSDL using the API?

Tags: api, wsdl, salesforce

I need to access the Enterprise WSDL using the Salesforce API in my Java app. Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce WSDLs are only available in the Salesforce UI, not through the API. You can get them at:

> **Setup** | **Develop** | **API**

If you find that need to get the Enterprise WSDL at runtime because your application needs to work with different sets of objects and fields, you should probably be using the Partner WSDL instead. It will allow you to get all the object and field descriptions at runtime and make dynamic API calls. There a little more work upfront, but results in a more flexible and resilient application. When the objects and fields change in the future, your application will continue to work without re-consuming the WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL is not available through the Salesforce API (to my knowledge). However, it is available through a REST call if you have the right information. First, you need a session token, generated through either an OAuth handshake or a username/password+security token handshake. You also need the name of the Apex class from which you generated the WSDL. With those two things, you can perform a GET. See the following pseudo-code for the requisite GET structure.

```
GET https://<SANDBOX_INSTANCE_URL>/services/wsdl/class/<APEX_WSDL_CLASS_NAME>?isdtp=p1

Headers:
  'Cookie' : 'sid=<SESSION_TOKEN>'
```

EDIT:
I verified that this works with both Enterprise/Partner WSDLs and WSDLs generated from custom Apex classes.

You can use the following generic URLs for these WSDLs, as of v41.0:

- Partner: https://<SANDBOX_INSTANCE_URL>/soap/wsdl.jsp
- Apex: https://<SANDBOX_INSTANCE_URL>/services/wsdl/apex
- Metadata: https://<SANDBOX_INSTANCE_URL>/services/wsdl/metadata
- Tooling: https://<SANDBOX_INSTANCE_URL>/services/wsdl/tooling
- Tooling (Enums): https://<SANDBOX_INSTANCE_URL>/services/wsdl/tooling?enumStyle=ALL_STRONG